# Calculating cell statistics for subset of bands in multiband raster

Tags: arcpy, raster, arcmap, spatial-analyst, cell-statistics

I have a multiband raster representing hourly air quality. I would like to calculate average air quality using a subset of the hours. If I want to calculate the daily average, I can use the [Cell Statistics](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/cell-statistics.htm) tool to calculate the mean value.

How can I do the same, but only for hours 8-16 (bands 8-16) using ArcPy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a raster layer for each band for bands 8-16 and then provided a list of each of the raster layers to the Cell Statistics tool:

```
# Provide path to raster
input_multiband_raster = r"C:\my_multiband_raster.tif"

# Create empty list for input layers
layers = []

# Loop over the bands indices for each hour to be used in the average
for i in range(8,16):

    # Name of the output layer for this band
    tlayer = "MakeRas_tif" + str(i)
 
    # Create raster layer
    arcpy.MakeRasterLayer_management(in_raster=input_multiband_raster, out_rasterlayer=tlayer, band_index=i)

    # Add raster layer to list
    layers.append(tlayer)

# Calculate mean value for the selected layers
output_mean = arcpy.sa.CellStatistics(layers, "MEAN", "DATA")
```